# Find radius of convergence of $\sum_n a_nz^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Here's a problem from Lang's Complex Analysis book:

> Let $R$ be the radius of convergence of the series $\sum_n \dfrac{a(a+1)...(a+n)}{b(b+1)...(b+n)}z^n$ where $a,b\in\mathbb C$ such that $b\notin \{0,-1,-2,...\}$. Show $R\geq1$ and mention when $R=\infty$.

The exercise is straightforward: one simply needs to compute $\dfrac{1}{R}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{|a(a+1)...(a+n)|^{1/n}}{|b(b+1)...(b+n)|^{1/n}}$

To evaluate this limit, note we can write for any complex number $c$ that $|c+n|=\sqrt{(Re(c)+n)^2+(Im(c))^2}$

Thus essentially in the above we need to compute $\sqrt{\lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{i=0}^n\left[\dfrac{(Re(a)+i)^2+(Im(a))^2}{(Re(b)+i)^2+(Im(b))^2}\right]^{1/n}}$

Turning it into log, it is enough to evaluate $\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n \log\left(\dfrac{(Re(a)+i)^2+(Im(a))^2}{(Re(b)+i)^2+(Im(b))^2}\right)$

Now note as $n\to\infty$ we have $\log\left(\dfrac{(Re(a)+n)^2+(Im(a))^2}{(Re(b)+n)^2+(Im(b))^2}\right)\to\log(1)=0$ so the averages converge to $0$, so the exponential (i.e. our desired limit) goes to $1$.

So it seems there is no question of the limit being **at most** $1$ as the limit is precisely equal to $1$. And also $R=\infty$ does not occur.

Where am I wrong?

PS: Of course if $a=0$ then $R=\infty$ trivially. Anything apart from this?

Comment: An infinite sum of terms approaching zero is not necessarily zero.

Comment: Isn't it easier to use ratio test?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For $R=\infty$, consider that the sum may simply be finite in some cases.

Comment: Yes, how could I miss that? But otherwise, the correct $R=1$ only, right?

Comment: Correct: if the sum is infinite, the radius of convergence is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Another hint: is to use [the ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius). Noting 
$$c_k=\frac{a(a+1)...(a+k)}{b(b+1)...(b+k)}$$
and assuming that $a \notin \{0, -1, -2, ...\}$ then:

$$R=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left|\frac{c_k}{c_{k+1}}\right|=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left|\frac{b+k+1}{a+k+1}\right|=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left|\frac{\frac{b}{k+1}+1}{\frac{a}{k+1}+1}\right|=1$$

However, if $a \in \{0, -1, -2, ...\}$, e.g. let's assume $a=-p, p \in \mathbb{N}$, then $c_k=0, \forall k\geq p$ and the root test gives $R=\infty$.